# Do non-maskable interrupts have priority over the current instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt

I'm working on an Assembly course and the following question has puzzled me. I've tried to replicate it in code, but it's hard to reproduce the situation in a simulator.

> A value of 5 is stored at 0x0000100. At the exact same moment when the processor is evaluating a **INCB 0x0000100** instruction, an NMI interrupt is raised calling a sub-routine which multiplies the value at 0x0000100 by 2. What would be the final value at 0x0000100?

I'm a bit confused whether the *current* instruction will finish before the interrupt is processed, or if it is immediately canceled.

Comment: The current instruction will be completed first. The manual says: _All interrupts are guaranteed to be taken on an instruction boundary_.

Comment: The interrupt sequence will begin at the end off the current instruction cycle. Some instructions take longer than others to complete. The time taken from the signal input until the interrupt begins is called its *latency*. So the value at address `0x0000100` will be `6` at the start of the NMI handling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NMI handlers use exactly the same fetch, process, write cycles as any other code while they are running (you don't want to replicate gates unnecessarily). It simply saves the processor state, pushes the current program counter onto the stack and changes the PC to the interrupt handler. When return from interrupt is called, it carries on where it left off.

How could it do that if it allowed partial instructions?

(Not meaning to be snarky - I just find "why" more interesting than "what")